# SQL - Subtract the sum of certain records from the total

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table

```
ITEMID  | TYPE          | QTY |
-----------------------
...
134     |TOTALINDEPOT   | 169 |
134     |UNUSED         |  70 |
134     |FAULTY         |  15 |
134     |DAMAGED        |   1 |
134     |DELAYED        | 100 |
...
```

What is an efficient way to retrieve the quantity of available items with id 134 (excluding these of delayed type)? Result is 83 => (169-(70+15+1)).
I implemented it with `(SELECT qty FROM tableA WHERE type='TOTALINDEPOT' AND itemid='134') - (SELECT SUM(qty) ... WHERE TYPE IN ('UNUSED', 'FAULTY', 'DAMAGED')) AND itemid='134'`, but looking for something more elegant.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Could you post what you'd like to see as the result?

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table? And a possible result set. Now that would be elegant :).

Comment: Added information to the question

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Oracle

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
SELECT a.ITEMID,
    (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM tbl WHERE TYPE = 'TOTAL' AND ITEMID = a.ITEMID) -
    (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM tbl WHERE TYPE <> 'TOTAL' AND ITEMID = a.ITEMID) AS available
FROM tbl a
GROUP BY a.ITEMID
```

**Result**

```
| ITEMID | AVAILABLE |
----------------------
|    134 |        83 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcc61/3)

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you?

```
SELECT a.total1 - a.total2
FROM 
(
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type='total' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as total1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type<>'total' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as total2
  FROM table WHERE itemid = 134
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
SELECT SUM(QTY) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [TYPE] IN ('UNUSED', 'FAULTY', 'DAMAGED') THEN QTY END) AS TotalSum
FROM TABLE1
```

[DEMO:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ace2f/6)